# mongoengine Filed containing Fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm currently trying to write a some Data to my Database. I want to Store information about a File inside the Database, but the Problem is that my File Field contains information about the owner which is a own Field. I already googled how to accomplish this but I wasn't successful...

My current Approach is to store the User Filed inside a DictField, but won't be the Solution for this Problem. I have almost no experience with Databases so any Help is welcome.

Is there some way to Link to a User inside of my File or how can I accomplish this?

```
class User(Document):
    uid = UUIDField(...)
    ...

class File(Document):
    fid = UUIDField(...)
    owner = User <--
```

I hope my short illustration helps solving the Problem.

Anyway, thanks a lot already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further research I found the Solution. It seems that reading the Documentation helps a lot ^^

[ReferenceField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#reference-fields) is what I was searching for. As described in the Documentation I simply have to add this Filed like this to my `File` Class:

```
class User(Document):
    uid = UUIDField(...)
    ...

class File(Document):
    fid = UUIDField(...)
    owner = ReferenceField(User)
```

Before you can add the `User` to the `File` you have to `save()` the User so he can be referenced.

Access to the User is provided with this Query:

```
file.owner.uid  # This would get the Files Owner UID
```